# chaining multiple epoll instances

Tags: linux, select, epoll

Can we add file descriptor returned by epoll_create to another epoll instance using epoll_ctl. how do we chain multiple epoll instances in the application, lets say if we have 2 epoll instances one coming from the application and the other coming from library. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **man epoll**

Q3  Is the epoll file descriptor itself poll/epoll/selectable?

A3  Yes.  If an epoll file descriptor has events waiting, then it will indicate as being readable.